# Error in loading a file into EMR distributed cache using elastic-mapreduce

Tags: python, ruby, hadoop, mapreduce, emr

I'm using below command to launch a cluster.

```
./elastic-mapreduce --create \
 --stream \
 --cache  s3n://bucket_name/code/totalInstallUsers#totalInstallUsers \
 --input s3n://bucket_name/input \
 --output s3n://bucket_name/output \
 --mapper s3n://bucket_name/code/mapper.py \
 --reducer s3n://bucket_name \
 --jobflow-role EMR_EC2_DefaultRole \
 --service-role EMR_DefaultRole \
 --debug \
 --log-uri s3n://bucket_name/logs
```

and I always got below error message. If I remove the --cache statement, the cluster will be launched successfully.
Error: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000002c28ba0>
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:806:in`steps'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:1232:in `block in enact'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:1232:in`map'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:1232:in `enact'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:49:in`block in enact'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:49:in `each'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:49:in`enact'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/commands.rb:2422:in `create_and_execute_commands'
/home/ubuntu/data_processing/elastic-mapreduce-cli.rb:13:in`'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
./elastic-mapreduce:6:in `'

Reason to use --cache is that I wish from mapper.py I can open the datafile via "with open('./totalInstallUsers', 'r') as infile:

could anyone give me a clue? thanks

Comment: The ruby cli is deprecated. Please set up AWS CLI, adjust for changes and try again (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/CLI_CreateStreaming.html).

Comment: Thanks Christopher, that's what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Here to post the solution I got, hopefully helpful for others. 
Using AWS EMR, the command look like:

```
aws emr create-cluster 
    --name "cluster--name" 
    --enable-debugging 
    --log-uri s3://bucket-name/logs 
    --ami-version 3.7.0 
    --use-default-roles 
    --ec2-attributes KeyName=your-key 
    --instance-type m3.xlarge 
    --instance-count 3 
    --auto-terminate 
    --steps file://./streaming.json

And in Streaming.json, it looks like: 
[ 
    { 
    "Type": "STREAMING", 
    "Name": "Streaming program", 
    "ActionOnFailure": "TERMINATE_CLUSTER", 
    "Args": [ 
            "-files","s3://bucket-name/code/mapper.py,s3://bucket-name/code/reducer.py", 
            "-mapper","mapper.py", 
            "-reducer","reducer.py", 
            "-input","s3://bucket-name/input", 
            "-output","s3://bucket-name/output", 
            "-cacheFile", "s3://bucket_name/code/data-file-name#new-file-name" 
            ] 
    } 
]
```